# Font Awesome 4.1 Icons not working?

Tags: css, web, font-awesome

I have tried adding this code to my header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And when that didn't work, adding the entire project from the [Font Awesome GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/css)

Neither seem to work. All the pre 4.1 icons load fine, but the ones I need from 4.1 one don't (namely fa-cube). Anybody else having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `<i>` tag to add `Font Awesome`. This is how you'd make use of it:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
</div>
```

You can see this here-> http://jsfiddle.net/Zv8mH/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your posted *CSS* file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.1.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.1.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

*Fonts* have to be added to the project too, cause they are referenced by the *CSS* file.

Comment: I actually tested the GitHub project again by creating a local directory on my machine and it worked...and all I needed was the <link>. But when I put the project on my Business Catalyst server the cube stops showing up...

Comment: Fonts are added to your project? Are they loaded?

Comment: When I tested on my desktop all I had was the FontAwesome Folder, and an index file with a link to the font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/JfGVE/386/) you can verify. It's working.

The code is the following:

```
<span class="fa fa-cube"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ensure the following:
1. You have linked the correct stylesheet 
2. You have enclosed the icon class with <i> tag
<i class="fa fa-cubes"></i>

You can find more icons available with fontawesome at http://fontawesome.io/icons/
```